# codecademy expressJS post request comes back undefined

Tags: javascript, express, undefined, push

Here is my repository: [https://github.com/Fluckerbust/quoteAPI](https://github.com/Fluckerbust/quoteAPI/tree/7a91bd2443fe1de3fc11efc5ed6badbdd9644bc6)

Essentially it asked me to build a post request to push a quote and the person from the new-quote page.

I am able to console log the values, no problem, but when it comes to pushing them to the array it pushes 2 undefined values.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried many ways to get it to come through but it refuses to push anything except undefined. I'm assuming it's some sort of Syntax error of not calling the values correctly or the push isn't setup correctly.

(what I coded) Server.js:

```
app.post('/api/quotes', (req, res, next) => {
    const quote = req.query.quote
    const person = req.query.person
    const newQuoteAdd = {quote:quote, person:person}
    function pushQuote (quoteText, attribution)  {
        quotes.push({quote:quoteText, person:attribution});
    }
    
    if(quote && person){
        console.log(quote)
    console.log(person)
    console.log(quote, person)
        pushQuote({quote, person});
        res.status(201).send({quote:quote, person:person});
    } else {
        res.status(400).send("There was an error processing the request. Please try again.")
    }
});
```

(precoded for the project) add-quote.js:

```
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-quote');
const newQuoteContainer = document.getElementById('new-quote');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const quote = document.getElementById('quote').value;
  const person = document.getElementById('person').value;

  fetch(`/api/quotes?quote=${quote}&person=${person}`, {
    method: 'POST',
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(({quote}) => {
    const newQuote = document.createElement('div');
    newQuote.innerHTML = `
    <h3>Congrats, your quote was added!</h3>
    <div class="quote-text">${quote.quote}</div>
    <div class="attribution">- ${quote.person}</div>
    <p>Go to the <a href="index.html">home page</a> to request and view all quotes.</p>
    `
    newQuoteContainer.appendChild(newQuote);
  });
});
```

I've tried different variations of {quote, person}, {[quote, person]}, {quote:quote, person:person} and various other ways of saying pulling those values and trying to push those values. It should take whatever is typed into the Quote Text and person inputs and then take those values and push them into an already existing array. instead it comes back undefined from the values. Even though the console.log shows the values coming through fine.

Below is the code I think is having an issue.

```
function pushQuote (quoteText, attribution)  {
        quotes.push({quote:quoteText, person:attribution});
    }
    
 pushQuote({quote, person});
        res.status(201).send({quote:quote, person:person});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already found the problematic code:

```
function pushQuote(quoteText, attribution) {
    quotes.push({ quote: quoteText, person: attribution });
}

pushQuote({ quote, person });
```

In the `pushQuote({ quote, person })` call, `{ quote, person }` uses a [property definition shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions) to create an object with 2 properties (*quote* and *person*). This could also be written as `{ quote: quote, person: person }`.

So you are passing a single parameter to `pushQuote()` which is expecting 2 parameters.

---

I'll assume that you meant to call `pushQuote()` like this:

```
function pushQuote(quoteText, attribution) {
    quotes.push({ quote: quoteText, person: attribution });
}

pushQuote(quote, person); // removal of { and }
```

This passes `quote` as the first parameter and `person` as the second parameter, instead of creating an object and passing that as single parameter.

---

Alternatively you could also adjust `pushQuote()` to accept your current way of invoking the function:

```
function pushQuote(quoteObject) {
    quotes.push(quoteObject);
}

pushQuote({ quote, person });
```

This expects a single parameter and pushes it to the `quotes` variable.

---

Another alternative would be to use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) to destructure (unpack) the passed object.

```
function pushQuote({ quote, person }) { // destructuring/unpacking
    //             └───────2───────┘
    quotes.push({ quote, person }); // object literal with property shorthand
    //          └───────3───────┘
}

pushQuote({ quote, person }); // object literal with property shorthand
//        └───────1───────┘
```

This first uses the object property shorthand to create an object with the properties *quote* and *person* (see `1`) and passes it as a **single parameter** to `pushQuote()`. The function then destructures the object into the variables `quote` and `person` (see `2`). Then uses the object property shorthand notation again to create a new object with the properties *quote* and *person* (see `3`) and pushes it into the `quotes` variable.

---

**In the second and third solution naming is important!** If the variables `quote` and `person` have different names, then you can't use the property definition shorthand. You'll have to change the `pushQuote()` call to:

```
pushQuote({ quote: someQuoteVariable, person: somePersonVariable });
```

Because `pushQuote()` expects a single object parameter that has the *quote* and *person* properties.

The first solution is position based, so you can do:

```
pushQuote(someQuoteVariable, somePersonVariable);
```